# Can I access a device using Android HCE from a device running Android 4.3 (or below)?

Tags: android, nfc, android-4.3-jelly-bean, hce, contactless-smartcard

I have developed an app that emulates a contactless smartcard using Android HCE and an app that accesses (reads) this emulated card. Both run on Android 4.4 (KitKat) and above.

No I would like to develop the reader-side for devices that run Android 4.3 (or lower). Is it possible to access a device that uses Android HCE from a device with an API level < 19? I do not want to use the Android Beam feature.

Comment: Before we can give you an answer, you should first understand your problem. What is it that you really need?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

No, that's not possible. By default, two Android devices (when held together) will communicate in *peer-to-peer mode*. This is the case even if one or both devices support host card emulation. Once an Android device successfully established a peer-to-peer mode link, it *won't try to use reader/writer mode* on the same target.

In order to permit the Android HCE-emulated card to be visible to (accessible from) a second Android device, that second device must **disable** its peer-to-peer mode capabilities and operate only in reader/writer mode.

This is exactly what you do with the Android reader mode API (that you seem to use in your reader app for Android 4.4). Using `NfcAdapter.enableReaderMode()` with the flags `FLAG_READER_NFC_A` and `FLAG_READER_NFC_B` forces Android to act in reader/writer mode and to *disable* peer-to-peer mode.

As this API (or something equivalent) is not available on Android 4.3 and below (i.e. before API level 19), you have no means to programmatically<sup>1</sup> disable peer-to-peer mode. Consequently, your reader app on Android 4.3 can't communicate with an Android HCE emulated card.

---

<sup>1</sup>) Note that disabling Android Beam in Settings **won't** disable peer-to-peer mode either. This will just disable the Beam capabilities that would normally run on top of peer-to-peer-mode.